# Why i get Not found for JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, pug-loader

When i want to put js file i get this error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/src/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Pug with Java</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <script src="src/app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Structure of the project

[image: project structure]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Try `<script src="app.js"></script>`

Comment: where is your html file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to build your app. If you open package.json you will see scripts to build the app.

Build it and include the js from build folder. If your index.html and js file is in same location you dont need to `src/` in script src.

Most probably `app.js` will be changed to `main.js` after build. Check it in build folder.

Build command will be something like

```
npm run prod
```

or

```
npm run prod-en
```

Once you do a build you will not have the `src` folder.

Comment: I don't know to build a app,i just get it the pug from github and i wanted to add JS

Comment: I just changed in index.js and now error say                                                               
     index.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: and btw the index html is in tmp because i use PUG

Comment: Did you check the `installation` and `usage` docs https://github.com/marianzburlea/pug-starter#installation  After that you need to build the app

Comment: i used npm run prod and create me a folder with index.html but still doesn't work

Comment: What all files do you have in the  build folder, what is the content of index.html. Can you please update these in your question?

Comment: I fixed that i make it a clone clean from github and make a src/asset/js folder and put the js there and now he see my js.

Answer (score 0):

In which file is your HTML? If it's in index.pug you should try `<script src="app.js"></script>` as it's in the same folder.

Comment: https://ibb.co/MMpHyLX  it's in tmp,still get this error

Comment: Ah, in that case it's easy, change it to <script src="../src/app.js"></script>. Unless you use a static folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you use express.js ,try this ,
add this code  `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "")));` into your app.js to identify the exacly path. to your file.js